# Remove key from multiple nested jsonb objects with unknown keys in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a column of jsonb objects that look similar, but have different top level keys in each row. Each record looks something like this, but with different top level keys:

```
{
   "10": {
      "key": "value",
      "toDelete": "value"
   },
   "42": {
      "key": "value",
      "toDelete": "value"
   },...
}
```

I need to do an update to remove the `toDelete` key/value from each object in each record in every row. It's easy enough to remove each one manually using the `#-` operator, but there could be hundreds or even thousands of top level keys in each record, so I need some sort of dynamic solution. I tried aggregating all the paths to delete into an array and removing all of them at once using `column #- array` where the array looks like `{{10, toDelete},{42,toDelete}...}` but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: If you are storing thousands of keys in jsonb, I think you are abusing postgresql. Perhaps you should consider extracting your data from json and store it in real SQL table(s) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the json column is an anti-pattern, I fully agree with the comment by @mvp:

> ... you should consider extracting your data from json and store it in real SQL table(s) instead.

If you are forced to play with the original data, use the function:

```
create or replace function remove_nested_object(obj jsonb, key_to_remove text)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(key, value- key_to_remove)
    from jsonb_each(obj)
$$;

update my_table
set json_column = remove_nested_object(json_column, 'toDelete')
where json_column::text like '%"toDelete":%';
```

Comment: I got a similar answer using a plpgsql stored procedure to build a query string that removes all of them. It's super slow though. This works way better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using @klin 's function I got this error

ERROR:  cannot delete from scalar
CONTEXT:  SQL function "remove_nested_object" statement 1
SQL state: 22023

because I tried to make it work recursively.
I ended up with this function that deletes an unwanted key on any level of json hierarchy. It also deletes several keys for the sake of economy and convenience

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.remove_nested_object(
    obj jsonb,
    keys_to_remove text[])
    RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL SAFE 
AS $BODY$
declare
    returned_object jsonb;
    key_to_remove text;
begin
    returned_object := obj;

    case
        when jsonb_typeof(obj) = 'object' then
            foreach key_to_remove in array keys_to_remove
            loop
                returned_object := returned_object - key_to_remove;
            end loop;
            return jsonb_object_agg(key, remove_nested_object(value, keys_to_remove)) from jsonb_each(returned_object);
        when jsonb_typeof(obj) = 'array' then 
            return (select jsonb_agg(remove_nested_object(item, keys_to_remove)) from jsonb_array_elements(obj) item);
        else return obj;
    end case;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Example of usage:

```
select remove_nested_object(yourJsonB, '{field1,field2,field3}')
```